# Can someone help me to translate this line of code in java?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

```
if (area >= 30 &&
    std::abs(1 - ((double)rect.width / (double)rect.height)) <= 0.2 && 
    std::abs(1 - (area / (CV_PI * std::pow(radius, 2)))) <= 0.2)
```

What I want to be translated is the `std::abs` and the `CV_PI * std::pow`.

I've search the net for `std::abs` equivalent to java and failed to find any. Please help. Wasn't able to search for `CV_PI * std::pow` since I can't still find the `std::abs`.

Comment: In you have Intelli or the Andriod IDE, press `left shift` twice and type `abs` to search for it or any function, method, class, file etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the `Math` class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

```
 Math.PI
 Math.pow(...)
 Math.abs(...)
 etc.
```

Comment: BTW `Math.pow(x, 2)` is much slower than `x * x`

Comment: @PeterLawrey even when both operands are double? Uhwell, that may not be this surprising after all...

Comment: @fge well `Math.pow(x, 2.0)` is also slower than `x * x` ;) Note, the power has to be 0, 1 or 2 for it to be faster to not use it. Possibly 3...

Comment: @PeterLawrey in fact I was trying to figure out whether there would be a difference if `x` itself were a double. I guess it'd be a nice simple example of JMH usage....

Comment: @fge on some platforms `x * x` is faster when x is a double vs a long.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you're not helping matters, you know that? :p

Comment: @fge I have been told by a Java expert that I have an evil mind.

Comment: @PeterLawrey still, it may be an interesting use case for JMH; while using it for another project I have witnessed a behavior which I found strange, so if I can reproduce with as simple a scenario as x*x vs Math.pow(), that'll be a question from me very soon... Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @fge I suggest you try it on different processors esp Intel vs AMD. Also ARM if you can.

Comment: @PeterLawrey meh, this could be discussed at length; but I don't have the leisure of testing on multiple CPU arches currently, only my own machine. And the difference in performance between the two is close to negligible... But then it may be that I use JMH incorrectly, too :/

Comment: Try on multiple processors? But Java is write once, run everywhere! It says so in the promotional material! Marketting wouldn't lie!